# First-order RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, ltspice

I have a first-order RC circuit without source and capacitors initially charged to +5 V and -4 V as shown in the figure.

Initially charge sharing takes place between capacitors and v(a) = v(b) = 0.5 V. Then the voltage should get discharged through the resistor exponentially with a time constant of 2RC. But I am observing a linear discharge instantaneously (in ps).
Why did this happen?

[image]

PS: zero-voltage source was included just to assign initial voltages across capacitors

Comment: You should use a "timed" switch (?) ...

Answer (score 3):

Your voltage source has zero series resistance so it will charge and discharge the capacitors instantaneously.  If you want something different you’ll need a resistor in series with it.

Comment: Yeah, charging happens instantaneously. But I am talking about the discharging part. It should be exponential with a time constant of 2RC. But here it is linear.

Comment: Do you think your voltage source is still zero impedance when it switches to zero?  If it switched to a non-zero voltage I would certainly expect that to be the case.